# Taking a sub panel in sugarcrm and making it into two, one that displays entries depending if a checkbox is checked, the other non checked entries

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Taking a sub panel in sugarcrm and making it into two, one that displays entries depending if a checkbox is checked, the other non checked entries.

I have a module called mod_loaninvestor, and its sub panel is whole_subpanel_mod_loaninvestor_contacts

Now I know vardefs is where you create the duplicate and rename it like this

```
        <?php 
 //WARNING: The contents of this file are auto-generated


 // created: 2014-01-24 13:12:28
$layout_defs["Contacts"]["subpanel_setup"]['mod_loaninvestor_contacts'] = array (
  'order' => 100,
  'module' => 'mod_LoanInvestor',
  'subpanel_name' => 'default',
  'sort_order' => 'asc',
  'sort_by' => 'id',
  // 'where' => "(mod_LoanInvestor.active_investment == "1")",   
  'title_key' => 'LBL_MOD_LOANINVESTOR_CONTACTS_FROM_MOD_LOANINVESTOR_TITLE',
  'get_subpanel_data' => 'mod_loaninvestor_contacts',
  'top_buttons' => 
  array (
    /*
    0 => 
    array (
      'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopButtonQuickCreate',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButton',
      'mode' => 'MultiSelect',
    ),
    */
  ),
);

 // created: 2014-01-24 13:12:28
$layout_defs["Contacts"]["subpanel_setup"]['mod_loaninvestor_contacts1'] = array (
  'order' => 100,
  'module' => 'mod_LoanInvestor',
  'subpanel_name' => 'default',
  'sort_order' => 'asc',
  'sort_by' => 'id',
  'title_key' => 'LBL_MOD_LOANINVESTOR_CONTACTS_FROM_MOD_LOANINVESTOR_TITLE',
  'get_subpanel_data' => 'mod_loaninvestor_contacts',
  'top_buttons' => 
  array (
    /*
    0 => 
    array (
      'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopButtonQuickCreate',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButton',
      'mode' => 'MultiSelect',
    ),
    */
  ),

);

?>
```

How would I make it so the first one would only show entries with the following checked

and the other display only entries with that field unchecked?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're halfway there. On top of defining new layoutdefs, you need to create a new subpanel definition.

Dig into mod_LoanInvestor and the metadata/subpanels/default.php and copy it to default2.php or whatever you'd like to call it. You'll want to use a WHERE clause to separate the two.

https://gist.github.com/matthewpoer/8871568

Here's a gist where I'm doing this with transactions records to seperate scheduled (future) transactions from past (posted payments).